# Silly HTML issue that I cannot figure out regarding <div> tags and width being auto set

Tags: html, css

I'm developing something in asp.net and finally got round to creating the UI. I made a basic `<div>` element to wrap the content of my body in, and I notice that it auto fills the width to 100%. I create a new `.aspx` page to test it in, and the same results happen. So I create the following HTML document in notepad, save it as `test.html` and run it through Chrome, IE and Firefox and all three are returning a strip of `20px` high and `100%` width with a red background. Here's the code:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #tester
        {
            height: 20px;
            background-color: Red;
            border: 1px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="tester">

    </div>
</body>
```

Would anyone know what I could have done to make this so that it auto fills div elements to width: 100% on all browsers? I guess it's possible that I'm being absent minded and forgot that div elements did this automatically, but I'm 99% sure they didn't.

Thank you kindly,
Ben

Comment: sorry, i really don't understand your question - please rephrase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [CSS 101](http://www.css-101.org/block-level-elements/index.php) (BSD/MIT licences):

> The horizontal position and size of a non-floating, block-level element is determined by seven properties:
>
> - margin-left
> - border-left
> - padding-left
> - width
> - padding-right
> - border-right
> - margin-right
>
> The sum of these seven properties is always equal to the 'width' of the parent element.

So yes, you've been absent-minded! Block-level elements (such as `div`) automatically fill the width of their parent unless they've been told not to by `float`.

Comment: Or if you explicitly change them to inline or inline-block elements!

Answer (score 1):

`<div>`s are block-level elements, meaning they will automatically fill the horizontal space of their parent. Unlike inline elements such as `<span>`, which only take up the space required by their content.

Answer (score 0):

DIVS are by default 100% of their parent element. So just set the width you need.

Also note that DIVs that have a width greater than their parent will by default also be completely visible unless you set the parent element to overflow:hidden.